# Is there a way to resize the Combobox entry size?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I know there are many ways to change the drop down list/list box font, my question is how could you adjust the entry field at the same time, the part circled in red. How do I make it the same size as the label next to it? In other word, how do i make the **drop down arrow** bigger?

```
label = ttk.Label(frame, text='truck id: ', anchor=w, font=bigger_font)
c = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=truckID, values=['1','2','3','4'])
c['state'] = 'readonly'
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.font', bigger_font)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a little vague.  What do you mean by "entry field?"

Comment: I edited my question, hope it is more clear now

Comment: By Label, do you mean "Truck ID" or 1/2/3/4?

Comment: @Miraj50 anyone is fine, just want to make it larger.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which illustrates what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Combobox` has a **width** attribute which lets you control its size. The `width` is in terms of the number of characters. So for example, if you know that your combobox entries are single digit numbers, you can set the width attribute as, say 1. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tList = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], state="readonly", width=1)
tList.current(0)
tList.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Now see, if you change the width to 2.

[image]

It is exactly half the size of the combobox entry.

Basically, if you know what kind (length) of entries your combobox will contain, you can control its size.

If you want it to be taller in height, manipulate its `font` attribute.

`tList = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], state="readonly", width=2, font="Verdana 16 bold")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want it to be wider, I want it to be taller, in height, not in width

Comment: But the number displayed in that field is still small, how do you make it taller as well and also bold

Comment: Simple, add `font` attribute. For eg. `ttk.Combobox(root, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], state="readonly", width=1, font="Verdana 12 bold")`. See new edit.

Comment: @Aaron_Geng Also since you are using some `bigger_font` for the Label. Try using the same for the combobox as well.